# How and where do you call for achievement to be unlocked and displayed in google play games

Tags: android, google-play-services, achievements

I have made five achievements for my Android game. They are not Incremental achievements, How to I write the code that will unlock these achievements when the player has obtain an certain score e.g. 20. And where do I write this code? Im new to this, please help

Answer (score 1):

```
if (playerscore == 20) {
    Games.Achievements.unlock(ApiClient, "my_achievement_id");
}
```